# AttributeError: 'Mapper' object has no attribute after updating from SQLAlchemy 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue here with SQLAlchemy `1.4`.

With SQLAlchemy `1.3`, the calls to `aliased` work, like this

```py
    def query(self, patient_id):
        cls = self.__class__
        checkin = aliased(cls.relationship_one)
        study = aliased(checkin.relationship_two)

        # A query is done here
        # Omitted for brevity
        return result
```

However, if I updated SQLAlchemy to `1.4` I get the following error

`AttributeError: 'Mapper' object has no attribute 'relationship_two'`

---

I've gotten some similar errors after updating and using attributes referring to columns like

```py
alias = aliased(cls.relationship_1)
alias.my_column
```

But I fixed it by using

```py
alias.c.my_column # Note the .c here
```

---

Thanks for any help